# How to use reflection as callback in php

Tags: php, reflection

I have one class

```
   Class Mainclass{}
```

And another class which is

```
   Class Childclass extends Mainclass{}
```

Now i want to write callback in Mainclass which check if child class found with method, merge value and return?

How can i achieve using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to create an interface containing that method

```
interface XYZ
{
    public function myMethod();
}
```

And make your child class implement it

```
class Childclass extends Mainclass implements XYZ
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        //actual implementation
    }
}
```

Afterwards, your main class can easily check if it is implementing that interface:

```
class Mainclass
{
    public function whatever()
    {
        if ($this instanceof XYZ)
        {
            $this->myMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm fairly sure it would work but I really think this is bad design: a parent class should never depend on the implementation of its child classes. However since I don't know the context in which you're working, I'll leave this here and hope it helps you anyway.